# Undefined method 'save'

Tags: php, laravel

my method save is undefined, i dont know why.
this is about my laravel/php:

Environment .........................................................
Application Name ............................................ Laravel
Laravel Version ............................................. 10.14.1
PHP Version ................................................... 8.2.4
Composer Version .............................................. 2.5.8
Environment ................................................... local
Debug Mode .................................................. ENABLED
URL ....................................................... localhost
Maintenance Mode ................................................ OFF

Cache ...............................................................
Config ................................................... NOT CACHED
Events ................................................... NOT CACHED
Routes ................................................... NOT CACHED
Views ........................................................ CACHED

Drivers .............................................................
Broadcasting .................................................... log
Cache .......................................................... file
Database ...................................................... mysql
Logs ................................................. stack / single
Mail ........................................................... smtp
Queue .......................................................... sync
Session ........................................................ file

this is controller where i am using that method:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\Provinces as ProvincesResourceCollection;
use App\Http\Resources\Cities as CityResourceCollection;
use App\Models\Province;
use App\Models\City;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Book;
```

and this is where the Save() method undefined

```
public function shipping(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $status = 'error';
        $message = "";
        $data = null;
        $code = 200;
        if ($user) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'address' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required',
                'province_id' => 'required',
                'city_id' => 'required',
            ]);
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->address = $request->address;
            $user->phone = $request->phone;
            $user->province_id = $request->province_id;
            $user->city_id = $request->city_id;
            if ($user->save()) {       // this is the save method
                $status = "success";
                $message = "Update Shipping Success";
                $data = $user;
            } else {
                $message = "Update Shipping failed";
            }
        } else {
            $message = "User not found";
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
            'data' => $data
        ], $code);
    }
```

this is my user model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'username', 'roles', 'address',
        'city_id', 'province_id', 'phone', 'avatar', 'status', 'api_token'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function generateToken()
    {
        $this->api_token = Str::random(60);
        $this->saveOrFail();
        return $this->api_token;
    }

   
}
```

i hope my save method is not undefined again, in this case i was making bookstore

Comment: Where is the save method defined?

Answer (score -1):

You should try this

```
public function shipping(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $status = 'error';
        $message = "";
        $data = null;
        $code = 200;
        if ($user) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'address' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required',
                'province_id' => 'required',
                'city_id' => 'required',
            ]);
            $user = User::find($user->id);
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->address = $request->address;
            $user->phone = $request->phone;
            $user->province_id = $request->province_id;
            $user->city_id = $request->city_id;
            if ($user->save()) {       // this is the save method
                $status = "success";
                $message = "Update Shipping Success";
                $data = $user;
            } else {
                $message = "Update Shipping failed";
            }
        } else {
            $message = "User not found";
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $message,
            'data' => $data
        ], $code);
    }
```

Adding $user = User::find($user->id); line before assign values to model

Comment: What exactly would that do? `$user = Auth::user();` already assigns the auth'd user to `$user`, `User::find($user->id);` would return the same user

Answer (score -2):

You can use update method to update the auth user using user id.Here is your code.

```
public function shipping(Request $request)
            {
                $user = Auth::user();
                $status = 'error';
                $message = "";
                $data = null;
                $code = 200;
                if ($user) {
                    $this->validate($request, [
                        'name' => 'required',
                        'address' => 'required',
                        'phone' => 'required',
                        'province_id' => 'required',
                        'city_id' => 'required',
                    ]);
             

                    $user = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->update([
                        'name' => $request->name, 
                        'address' => $request->address
                        'phone' => $request->phone
                        'province_id' => $request->province_id
                        'city_id' => $request->city_id
                    ]);
                    if ($user) {       // this is the save method
                        $status = "success";
                        $message = "Update Shipping Success";
                        $data = $user;
                    } else {
                        $message = "Update Shipping failed";
                    }
                } else {
                    $message = "User not found";
                }
        
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => $status,
                    'message' => $message,
                    'data' => $data
                ], $code);
            }
```